# I get a 502 tunnel connection error when trying to deploy the WSO2 banking example

Tags: wso2

I am running through the WSO2 example at https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Retail+Banking+Sample with all the latest downloads on the DEV Studio and servers as of Oct 25, 2014. I get to the end and receive an error I have not come across.

*"Error while creating CAR"
An error occurred while creating or publishing the car for more details view the log. Transport error: 502 error: Tunnel Connection Failed.*

I configured all servers on one Win7 Workstation 64-bit, with ActiveMQ and MySQL and all the things correctly installed and working independently. I cannot get this last step to deploy the app and see how it will actually work. I need this to understand if/how I can use this in my scenario for our productions systems so any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: So did you follow the text in the error message and "for more details view the log"?

Comment: Yes I killed all the logs and started fresh as this is just a local instance.  Looking into the "wso2as-5.2.1\repository\logs" directory at the moment it happened and I get nothing in those logs mentioning that specific error. My ActiveMQ is running. MySQL is running locally and I can connect to it. wso2carbon.log and the http access .log are what I am looking at.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.7.0_71 and nothing shows new in the logs at all except HTTP "GET" status 200 messages. :(